# Using AngularJS $animate service to trigger JS defined animations

Tags: angularjs, ng-animate

I'm triggering animations manually through a directive - and it works fine.

```
element.bind('click', function() {
  $animate.addClass(element, 'my-animation');
});

.animation('.my-animation', function() {
    return {
        addClass: function(element) {
            element.html('<span>Animating</span>');
        }
    }
})
```

Here's a simple isolated working example in AngularJS 1.2.8:
http://plnkr.co/edit/5h5LbkqeL7i38NHSzisq?p=preview

But if I change the Angular version to 1.3+ the animation no longer triggers. I realize that the `$animate` service has gone through an overhaul and have tried various methods `$animate.animate()` etc.

Here's the same example failing in 1.3.8:
http://plnkr.co/edit/eTB1nmQLcO3nkpbaedqt?p=preview

Is it a bug? Am I daft? Help appreciated :)

Comment: that is very odd. I know very little about animation in AngularJS but I can't see why that wouldn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the breaking changes introduced with **1.3.0-RC.0** when the `$animate` service started to use promises instead of callbacks for animations.

Few excerpts from the [changelog](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#since-1217-and-130-beta10):

> Both the API for the cancallation method and the done callback for
>   $animate animations is different. Instead of using a callback function
>   for each of the $animate animation methods, a promise is used instead.

...

> keep in mind that you will still need to run $scope.$apply inside of
>   the then callback to trigger a digest.

...

> $animate.addClass, $animate.removeClass and $animate.setClass will no
>   longer start the animation right after being called in the directive
>   code. The animation will only commence once a digest has passed. This
>   means that all animation-related testing code requires an extra digest
>   to kick off the animation.

As `bind` is a jQuery/jqLite method it does not trigger the digest loop automatically for you like for example `ng-click` would.

To solve your problem simple wrap the code inside the attached event handler in a call to `$apply`:

```
element.bind('click', function() {
  scope.$apply(function() {
    $animate.addClass(element, 'my-animation');
  });
});
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/KTJs71WDLL4OXYmKTaYV?p=preview

Comment: Thank you for that detailed answer, I completely missed those changes.